# Vscode does not show linting warnings

Tags: eslint

I don't see the warnings in vscode, but I do in `cra`/`webpack`.

I've tried many things. I use `eslint`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the `Quiet` mode was on in vscode:

[image: Screenshot of setting]

Turned it off, and the warnings show again...